# How to restrict windows connection (PPTP) to a specific Port or App?

Tags: vpn, pptp

So lets say i want to restrict the PPTP (VPN) connection to specific applications, lets say for example Google Chrome uses the connection and other apps go through it.

There is an app called Proxifier that does same but it is for HTTPS/Http Proxies, i need one for PPTP. Is it possible? Is there any application that could do this?

Comment: Why simply put rules in the windows firewall?

Comment: Can we do that? How? (I Dont use windows firewall btw, got ESET Smart Security)